# Simple usage of 'host' metadata on Component seems perfectly valid

Tags: angular

In Angular 8 I have had time and time again the need to simply associate a class or classes to the host element of a component which zero conditional logic behind it. For example, I might want my component or directive:

`<app-button>Click Me</app-button>`

To **always** have the class `btn` on it no matter what. I dont want to force a developer to have to do:

`<app-button class="btn">Click Me</app-button>`

As that leads to people forgetting it, mistyping the class name and just not being DRY when we can be.

So that leads me to want to use the `host` property on the `@Directive` or `@Component` decorator in order to achieve this like so:

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'app-button',
  host: {
    class: 'btn'
  }
})
```

However, my TS linter has a rule `no-host-metadata-property` that was automatically set to `true` by default. After reading up on the subject in the post below I now understand why it is in some cases better to not use it since you can get stronger typing when using conditionals in the `host` key/value pairs. This makes total sense when you have something that complex, but in my case I have zero conditionals and I simply want my `:host` element to always have a class `btn`.

[Use @HostBindings instead host in angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45172565/use-hostbindings-instead-host-in-angular-4)

With that said, why is this rule defaulted to `true` when we create Angular 8 projects using the Angular Workspaces? I never turned this on, but it was enabled by default and really takes away from the simple use case I pointed out above. Is there another way to do this without `host` metadata that doesn't look and feel funky like this:

```
@HostBinding('class.btn') get isBtn() {
    // This feels stupid and overly engineered for something so simple
    return true;
}
```

Is this just a silly rule and I should just manually disable it and move on or am I missing some vital piece of information here?

Comment: check this:https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-06-03

Comment: @Chellappan I read over that and I understand that it is "preferred", but this only seems to make sense when your using complex conditionals to decide the value of the attribute. When you just need a simple "class" hardcoded to an immutable value, it seems overkill to wire up the HostBinding, no?

Comment: For simple scenario It's okay to use host meta data, Bcoz the only difference between hostdecorator and host meta data is @HostBinding only supports binding of values, while host metadata supports both binding and static values.